# how to read or retrieve data(personnel informations...) from smart card

Tags: c#, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I use ELYCTIS CL Reader to read data from smart card (I tried Biometric card and passport ) but only what I can retrieve is ATR code and the serial ID
is there any explanation to retrieve data from the card ,
this images explain what i trie to do ; I use a file that contains APDU and execute it,the code above is for execute button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgHzU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLHv5.png)

```
  private void buttonExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!m_iCard.Connected)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You first need to create a connection with the card.", "No connection available");
            }
            else
            {
                APDUScript script = (APDUScript)comboBoxScript.SelectedItem;

                if (script == null)
                {
                  
                }

                 byte[] baCmdBuffer;
                byte[] baRespBuffer;
                long count = 0;
                foreach (APDUInstruction ai in script.listAPDU)
                {
                    baCmdBuffer = APDUScript.toBytes(ai.Command);
                    count += baCmdBuffer.Length;

                    baRespBuffer = m_iCard.Transmit(baCmdBuffer, (uint)baCmdBuffer.Length);
                    count += baRespBuffer.Length;

                    // Add trace if required
                    if (checkBoxTrace.Checked)
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ai.Comment);
                        sb.Append("\r\n");

                        sb.Append("Send=>");
                        sb.Append(ai.Command);
                        sb.Append("\r\n");

                        sb.Append("Get<=");
                        String resp = APDUScript.toHexaString(baRespBuffer);
                        sb.Append(resp);
                        sb.Append("\r\n");

                        // Check the response with the expected one
                        Regex respRegex = new Regex("^" + ai.Resp.Replace('x', '.') + "$");
                        if (!respRegex.IsMatch(resp))
                        {
                            sb.Append("The response doesn't match the expected one ");
                            sb.Append(ai.Resp);
                            sb.Append("\r\n");
                        }

                        if (checkBoxTime.Checked)
                            sb.Append(String.Format("time {0:0,0 ms}.", StopTimer()));

                        sb.Append("\r\n");

                        addLogMsg(sb.ToString());
                    }
                }
                double time = StopTimer();
                addLogMsg(String.Format("{0:0,0} APDU bytes transferred in {1:0,0 ms}.\r\n", count, time));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            addLogMsg(exc.Message + "\r\n");
        }
    }

    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxLog.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: The idea here is that you show what you've tried, so we can see what's wrong. Please [edit] your question with the relevant code.

Comment: to communicate with the smart card i use a file that contain APDUs  (send and recieve responce), exemple here-> 
#Reader Authenticate
FF00000009090000000000000000
9000

#Desfire Load Keys
FF0000001F07010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
9000

#Reader Authenticate
FF00000009090000000000000000
9000
#Desfire Load Keys - TDES App1 key
FF0000001F070101A1B1C100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
9000
#Reader Authenticate
FF00000009090000000000000000
9000